# Get time object from milliseconds

Tags: python

What would be the best way to get a python time object form milliseconds int? For example:

```
ms = 2588832
datetime.timedelta(seconds = ?)
```

The answer I want to get is "00:43:08"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748491/how-do-i-create-a-datetime-in-python-from-milliseconds duplicate

Comment: @FirebladeDan: That answer shows how to create a timestamp, not a timedelta.

Comment: @Kevin - If you take the freeway home vs the frontage road still gets you home right? Same thing ultimately he wanted datetime. Both suffice

Comment: @FirebladeDan: No.  The other answer is flat wrong because it incorrectly assumes floating point division is accurate (it isn't).

Comment: I'm not going to argue for some other person's post. It was selected as the best answer.

Comment: @FirebladeDan: The correct answer is a variation of my answer plus some datetime arithmetic which OP didn't ask for.  I fail to see how that is a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create timedeltas [directly from milliseconds](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2588832)
```

Comment: Ok, great. I didn't know that that was possible. Thank you.