# Convert a timestamp to a DateTime field?

Tags: django, django-models, unix-timestamp

I've got a `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` in my model. However, I wish to update this field, and the format I'm receiving from my API is a UNIX timestamp. Can I somehow convert the format I receive from my API to the correct one? (eg `1640206232` to 2021-12-22 20:50:32).

Using postgres as my db if that matters..

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime

Answer (score 1):

Yes As mentioned by @Sevy in his comment you can use the following

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1640206232 
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz='UTC') # Or whatever timezone you want

print("dt_object =", dt_object)
print("type(dt_object) =", type(dt_object))
```

More info and how to convert the other way can be found here:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Forgot to add that I'd like to have it offset-aware, since I plan on comparing it with a `timezone.now()` value

Comment: Maybe check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325209/python-how-to-convert-unixtimestamp-and-timezone-into-datetime-object