# Converting epoch time to readable datetime

Tags: python

I am receiving this time through an API:

```
1644256800000
```

then I do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.fromtimestamp(1644256800000, timezone.utc)
```

and it returns the error: `{OSError}[Errno 22] Invalid argument`. Then if I remove 2 zeroes from the number:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.fromtimestamp(16442568000, timezone.utc)
```

the value goes through and returns the result: `2491-01-16 07:00:00` something like 400 years later.

What is the wrong part?

Comment: Likely millisecond epoch time vs seconds. What date do you think it is?

Comment: if what @dawg is saying is true, then you can do what's listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/748534/1366439  divide by 1000.0

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1644256800000/1000.0)` is `datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 13, 0)`

Comment: @dawg You're right. It just needed to be divided by 1000. Problem solved.

Comment: Beware the Y2038 problem -- that is the end of time with 32 bit epoch stamp. With 64 bits we can represent up to year 292277026596 which is 20x greater than the age of the universe.