# Convert "Unix Epoch Time" to human readable time using time.gmtime raises OSError "invalid argument"

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

Converting Unix Epoch time to readable time information. Trials are as per below. It throws an error "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument". Looks like the method does not like the given argument (1693063813031885), but it works great at https://unixtime.org/ where in "Your Time Zone".

```
import time
    
dt_ts = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(1693063813031885))
print(dt_ts)
```

Output should be `2023-08-26-11:30:13.031_885(UTC-05:00)`.

Comment: See [How do I create a datetime in Python from milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/748491/10197418). Besides, to get a result with UTC offset (UTC-05:00), you'll have to specify a time zone, since Unix time refers to UTC. Be careful: if you don't set a time zone, Python's naive datetime will resemble *local time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.gmtime` takes the number of seconds since the epoch as argument, what you have passed are microseconds.

You have to insert a decimal point before (or drop) the last 6 digits.

```
>>> time.gmtime(1693063813.031885)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2023, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=26, tm_hour=15, tm_min=30, tm_sec=13, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=238, tm_isdst=0)
```